# Protobuf oneof JSON syntax issue

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

I have a proto which is something like (not the exact case but very similair)

```
message football {
    repeated TeamDetails teamInfo= 1;
}

message TeamDetails {
    string position = 1;
    map<string, points> params = 2;
}

message points {
    oneof value {
         string string_value = 1;
         double number_value = 2;
         int32 int_value = 3;
    }
}
```

and I have a few questions about this;

- Is my oneof here okay and usable?
- I keep getting an issue when trying to run the following JSON to the end point, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

  ```
   "teamInfo": [
      {
          "position":"7th",
          "params": {"Manchester United": 51}
       }
    ]
  ```

gives me

`"Error getting request data: bad input: expecting start of JSON object: '{' ; instead got 51"`

I get the same error even after adding quotes around the 51, and if I replace the 'points' in the proto with <string, string> it would successfully work for the same JSON (but I don't want a string everytime, hence I'm trying to use the oneof but I'm getting this issue)

Comment: What programming language are you using to convert the json string into a protobuf object?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
 "teamInfo": [
    {
        "position":"7th",
        "params": {"Manchester United": { "int_value": 51 } }
     }
  ]
```

The type of `params` is `map<string, points>` but your JSON has the equivalent of `map<string, int32>`. That's valid JSON but it's not the equivalent of the proto type.

Because `points` is `oneof` i.e. `string` (or) `double` (or) `int32`, I think you need to replace (any) `oneof` with a generic JSON object that can represent multiple (possible) types i.e. `{...}` and, in this case, you want the `int32` field called `int_value`.